# css same class second time to be different style

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook, css-selectors, ipython

Questions similar to this might be asked already; however, I cannot find a solution for my case.

```
<div class="nb-cell nb-code-cell">
  <div class="A">
    ::before
  </div>
  <div class="A">
    ::before  <--to be different style
  </div>
</div>
```

I made some style for the `::before`, and wonder is it possible to change the style of the same `::before` but in the second class `A`?

extre information: this is the Jupyter IPython code converted into html so in some ways I cannot just simply remove the second `::before`.

Thank you.

Comment: You could go with `.A + .A::before`, but you might want to give a second class to your second `.A` and style this class instead.

Comment: It just works, thank you @AmauryHanser!